# InteliJ IDEA doesn't show proper templates when i press new > Scala in windows

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[image: 1]: [![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/015AO.png)
Scala template Doesn't show at all! Even after I made scala Directory as Sources Root.
[image: 2]: [![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlegP.png)
Any thoughts how to solve this? I use the newest InteliJIDEA

Answer (score 0):

Probably an open door, but did you intstall the scala plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/1347-scala

If so, another open door: did you restart IntelliJ?

Comment: Thanks. It seems I forgot to restart it. It works now.